# Dynamic memory Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic

> ```
> int main(int argc, char **argv) {
>     float *rainfall;
>     float rain_today;
>     // rainfall has been dynamically allocated space for a floating point number.
>     // Both rainfall and rain_today have been initialized in hidden code. 
>     // Assign the amount in rain_today to the space rainfall points to.
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Hi everyone. This is a really basic question but i havent found a solution yet. 
Isn't it just

```
rain_today = *rainfall
```

Comment: If anything it is the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

`rain_today = *rainfall;` would take the value pointed by `rainfall` and put it in `rain_today` (ideally NULL).

What you are being asked to do is putting the value of `rain_today` into the space pointed by the pointer `rainfall`

which is:

```
*rainfall = rain_today \\the value of rain_toady is COPIED to the space pointed by rainfall
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
rainfall = &rain_today \\rainfall points at the memory location of rain_today
```